# Using more than one ZeroMQ FORWARDED device

Tags: zeromq

Forwarder devices allow many producers to distribute to many consumers. However, this isn't very fault-tolerant. Is there any way to have two or more forwarders linked together?

I'm a user of ZeroMQ and I realize there's a line to be drawn between this and other more serious, decentralized queues, but the lack of this kindof makes the presence of these devices relatively limited in usefulness (though necessary in order to further 0MQ as a "complete" solution).